# Campo calculado não está editável no dbgrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Tenho um `DBGrid`, uma `FDQuery` e um `DataSource` que trazem valores de uma tabela. Neste `FDQuery` criei um campo calculado do tipo `Integer` chamado `mult`. O intuito desse campo é que o usuário escreva o valor do multiplicador no `grid`. O problema é que no campo do `DBGrid` ele não deixa digitar, fica só piscando o seletor:

[image: Multiplicador não recebe caracteres]

Já verifiquei as configurações do `DBGrid` e está editável, verifiquei o campo, mas não tenho ideia do que seja o motivo deste problema. Alguém pode me dizer como resolver?

Comment: Será que não esta com a propriedade `readonly = true`?

Comment: Então, eu verifiquei isso também, e não está com true, tentei diversas vezes habilitar e desabilitar pra ver se era bug...

Comment: Boa tarde Felipe.. Cara o CAMPO CALCULADO é para mostrar algo e não para ser digitado. Ate onde eu sei você não conseguira seu objetivo desse modo.

Comment: Ricardo, obrigado pela dica meu caro, vc está correto, eu estava fazendo errado mesmo...corrigi o problema e finalmente entendi o conceito rs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se deve ser digitado, o campo não pode ser calculado. Tem que ser um campo de dados. Se o dataset é resultado de uma query, você pode fazer o select de um valor fixo, por exemplo:

`SELECT 1 AS MULTIPLICADOR...`

Esse campo fica editável em tempo de execução. É importante limpar a propriedade providerflags do objeto de campo, para que o datasetprovider não tente atualiza-lo no banco de dados (se estiver utilizando clientdataset).
Outra possibilidade é criar o objeto de campo, com FieldKink = fkData. Isso pode ser feito por código, ou simplesmente no menu do FieldsEditor, escolha new field, com field type = data.

Comment: Muito obrigado sr Ricardo, ajudou bastante neste conceito, consegui resolver meu problema criando um campo com alias e limpando o providerflags. Sobre a segunda possibilidade, estou usando firedac, porém ao criar o campo do tipo data ele mostrou "erro catastrófico" rs, bom eu não me aprofundei nisso, mas ao terminar o projeto eu estudarei este conceito também. Até mais.